# Prove or disprove that if $f : R → R$ is differentiable and $f'$ is monotonic, then $f'$ must be continuous on R.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $f'$ is continuous, under the assumptions given in the title. I need to show that $\lim_{x->x_0} f'(x)$=$f'(x_0)$ exists. But I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Please use  [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) when typing your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative $f'$ always satisfies the [Darboux's property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)). Assume, WLOG that $f'(x_0)=0$ and $f'$ is increasing. Then $\limsup_{x\to x_0-} f'(x)\leq 0$ and it cannot be strictly negative as that would violate the Darboux property. Similarly $\liminf_{x\to x_0+} f'=0$. Can you complete this to a full proof?

Comment: if you assume that $f'(x_0)=0$ , why do you write without loss of generality ? it is loss of generality ! maybe there is no point like $x_0$ that $f'(x_0)=0$

Comment: @TinaAshtiani There is no difference; so write $f'(x_0)$ everywhere instead of zero; it's just longer.