# Prove that if $f$ is a differentiable function and $f'(x)$ is monotone, then $f'(x)$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Prove that if $f$ is a differentiable function and $f'(x)$ is monotone, then $f'(x)$ is continuous.

my work:

If $f'(x)$ is monotone, then it can only have jump discontinuities. If in addition to this the range of $f'(x)$ is an interval, then it is continuous. We may assume WLOG that $f'(x)$ is monotone increasing. Since $f$ is differentiable, if $f'(a)<L<f'(b),$ for some $a,b,L\in\mathbb{R},$ then $\exists c (a<c<b\wedge f'(c)=L).$ Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}.$ Pick $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a<x.$ Then $f'(a)<f'(x_0).$ Thus, by the least upper bound principle, $f'$ has a supremum, say $L.$ Let $\epsilon >0.$ We know that $L-\epsilon$ is not a supremum of $f',$ so by definition, $\exists x_1\in (a,x_0)$ such that $f'(x_1)>L-\epsilon.$ Since $f'$ is monotone increasing, we have $L-\epsilon<f'(x_1)<f'(x) \leq L$ for $x_1,x\in (a,x_0), x_1<x.$ Then $L-f'(x)< L-(L-\epsilon) = \epsilon.$ Thus, $|L-f'(x)|<\epsilon,$ so $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^-} f'(x) = f'(x_0).$ Similarly, using $\inf f'$ instead of $\sup f'$ and choosing another interval $(x_0,b),$ we can show that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}f'(x)=f'(x_0).$ Thus, $f'(x)$ is continuous on $x_0,$ so it is continuous.

However, can I even guarantee the existence of $a$ and $b$ using the fact that $f'(x)$ only has jump discontinuities?

I suppose I could use another approach involving the Darboux Theorem.

Comment: Use the Darboux theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis) to show $f'$ has no jump continuities at all.

Comment: Note that if f' has jump discontinuities f(x) cannot be differentiable by definition surrounding the jump. Take |x| as an example.

Comment: @GEdgar: Unless I am mistaken, the mean-value theorem is sufficient: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3424425/42969.